# UIPickerview changing with Search?

Tags: ios, database, pdf, uipickerview

So I'm trying to build an app which works alongside a database of PDF's. What I need is for the app to look at all of the files (PDF's) which are stored and to pull the certain files out, check this against the database and then show a list of which PDF's are available on a UIPicker.

The App would work like this;

1. The app checks the files and creates a picker wheel which has been populated with the countries for which there are plates in the directory.
2. The user selects the country using a picker wheel.
3. The app looks at the directory containing the plates and creates a list of the airfields in that country, displaying them in a second picker wheel.
4. The user selects an airfield.
5. The app checks those plates which belong to this airfield and displays a third picker wheel containing the plate titles.
6. The user clicks a particular plate and the app shows it, ideally within the app itself rather than by linking to Safari. This way we can have a ‘back’ button, apart from anything else, although I realise that this might be difficult to implement so may be something we change later.

To make this work I have created a standard format for the file names: 'Country-Airfield-Plate Name-Date.pdf', e.g. “UK-London Heathrow-ILS DME NDB 27-100214.pdf”. I've split this filename first at the full stop to get two strings: 'UK-London Heathrow-ILS DME NDB 27’ and ‘pdf’, and then we split the title at the hyphens to get ‘UK’, ‘London Heathrow’ and ‘ILS DME NDB 27’.

Comment: Now that you have posted your requirements document, please note that this website is for asking specific programming questions. Please redo your question to ask one clearly define programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a class that hold Country, Airfield, Plates. Then go through each and populate a list of countries uniquely. When they select, get all instances with that country. At the end you should have the one pdf. At that point you could just do Process.Start on the pdf.

```
Class plate{
  string country;
  string airfield;
  string plate;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a great way to tackle it! Is it possible you could go into a bit more detail? How would i could and combine each string?